# Statement printing at wrong line (Java Token problem)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printing, token

**Problem Outline:**

Given a string, 's', matching the regular expression [A-Za-z !,?._'@]+, I have to split the string into tokens. "We define a token to be one or more consecutive English alphabetic letters." Then, print the number of tokens, followed by each token on a new line.

**Sample input:**

```
He is a very very good boy, isn't he?
```

**Sample output:**

```
10
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

Explanation:

There are a total of 10 such tokens in string 's', and each token is printed in the same order in which it appears in string 's'.

**My approach**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        
        String[] tokens = s.split("[ !,?._'@]+");

        int tokenCount = 0;
        
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (!token.isEmpty()) {
                tokenCount++;
                System.out.println(token);
            }         
        }

        System.out.println(tokenCount);
    }
}
```

**My Output:**

```
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
10
```

The only problem I'm getting is that the number is being printed at the last line whereas I need it at first. I've tried playing about with the print statement and putting it in places where I thought it could work like exactly above the for loop and more places but it just either produces errors or prints the wrong values.

I just need some quick advice on how I can get the number printed at the top. Thanks.

Comment: You can count the number of tokens without using a loop or the `++` operator.  It's just the length of the array.

Comment: Small nit - if the line started with a delimiter the array length solution would produce an incorrect count hence the `isEmpty` check. Eg. `@He is a very very good boy, isn't he?`

Comment: @Computable Actually no, the first `String[]` item will be an empty String so it lenght will be `11`.

Comment: Exactly, the count is to be the number of tokens which is 10.

Comment: Oh, sorry I got confused for a little while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338547/markspace) said:

> You can count the number of tokens without using a loop or the ++
> operator. It's just the length of the array.

So, you don't even need a `tokenCount`, the `tokenCount` is the array size:

```java
System.out.println(tokens.length);

for (String token : tokens) {
    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

But, like [@Computable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17856705/computable) said:

> ...if the line started with a delimiter the array length solution would
> produce an incorrect count hence the isEmpty check...

So, if `s` can start with an matcher char, I see 2 solutions:

The first is verify the first char of `s` (and remove it if necessary) before the `split`:

```java
String regex = "[ !,?._'@]+";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String firstMatch = matcher.group();
    if (s.startsWith(firstMatch)) {
        s = s.substring(firstMatch.length());
    }
}

String[] tokens = s.split(regex);
```

And the second is use a `List<String>` based on your code:

```java
List<String> resultTokens = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String token : tokens) {
    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        resultTokens.add(token);
    }
}

System.out.println(resultTokens.size());
resultTokens.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Note**: Using the `List<String>` you don't need to use the `tokenCount`, you can just call [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> nonEmptyTokens = new ArrayList<>();

for (String token : tokens) {
    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        nonEmptyTokens.add(token);
    }         
}

System.out.println(nonEmptyTokens.size());

for (String token : nonEmptyTokens) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

May be you can use `size()` of new arraylist.